# How to get default DarkMode "tinted" colors of NSWindow titlebar and content view background?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindow, appkit, nscolor

### Setup:

Mac OS Monterey 12.3.1 (21E258)

### Steps

0. Activate Dark Mode.
1. Launch Xcode.
2. File > New > Project > macOS > App, click "Next".
3. Product Name: ColorTest, Interface: Xib, Language: Objective-C
4. Location: Dektop, click "Create"
5. Product > Run

### Result

See ColorTest app window launch. The window titlebar color and window content view background color are both slightly tinted to match the currently selected Desktop background. These are solid colors. They are *not* semi-transparent "material" colors.

[image]

These same tinted colors can be seen by launching the "General" System Preference pane.

[image]
[image]

### Problem

I want to get these two colors (solid yet tinted titlebar color and solid but tinted window content background color) programmatically so I can paint them at runtime inside of `-[NSView drawRect:]`. I expect something like this:

```
NSColor *color = [NSColor windowBackgroundColor];
[color setFill];
NSRectFill(self.bounds);
```

I thought `-[NSColor windowBackgroundColor]` might return one or the other of these colors, but it does not. I have checked many other such standard color methods of `NSColor`, but none of them match these two colors.

It seems like it should be extremely simple to find these two colors at runtime. But I'm stumped. Can't find them. Where are they?

Answer (score 2):

You need `NSVisualEffectView` with `.behindWindow` blendingMode with .contentBackground and .titlebar materials. And then using those colors in drawRect will result in what you see.

Comment: I had tried that but was missing the `-blendingMode`.  ‍♂️ Although I think your answer is not quite correct... When I use the settings you suggest, it seems the views take on the desired color automatically, and anything I do in `-drawRect:` is completely ignored. This should get me close enough tho. Unless more surprises await, I can take it from there… thx!!!

Comment: Hm, I spoke too soon. This does not produce the desired result. The view with the `NSVisualEffectMaterialTitlebar` material appears semi-transparent and content from behind the window shows thru. As mentioned above, I don't want that effect. I want the same effect as the window's titlebar, which is fully opaque.

Comment: For anyone finding this, the `NSVisualEffectMaterialTitlebar` material actually should use the `NSVisualEffectBlendingModeWithinWindow` blending mode (as implied by Jonny's answer below). Typically, there would also be a view behind it covering the whole window that uses the `NSVisualEffectBlendingModeBehindWindow` blending mode to get the normal tinted background.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `NSVisualEffectView` with blending mode set to `.withinWindow`.

```
    let effectView = NSVisualEffectView(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
    effectView.blendingMode = .withinWindow
    effectView.material = .titlebar // or .windowBackground
    view.addSubview(effectView)
```